# Wifi Authentication Problem on Android

Tags: wi-fi

I am not sure if this is really an Android problem, but I have reasons to believe so. Please let me know if not.

I am trying to connect to a WiFi network. This network redirects me to an authentication page (in the HTML viewer). This worked perfectly fine until a few days ago. Now, in the HTML viewer, after I authenticate it just shows `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. I thought it could be a problem with the HTML viewer, so I turned to Google Chrome for authentication. This worked at first. But now, even Chrome throws an error `405 Method not allowed`.

I think the problem could be the Android device, because I am able to connect to the WiFi with my laptop, which runs on Ubuntu. But, I am not really sure.

Any suggestions or solutions to solve or diagnose this?

My Android version is 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing another browser on Android. I tried firefox, same problem, with Brave it worked.

I have the same problem too, and it appeared about 10 days ago too. Maybe a security update from Chrome ? I have Huawei P8 Lite (ALE-L21) Latest Chrome app Android 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Been having a similar issue for the last one week...couldn't connect to my company's guest wi-fi. Called helpdesk and they connected with Cisco. Apparently, there is a bug with the latest Andriod Chrome browser that has caused this. You need to login with a browser that isn't Chrome or Firefox.

I installed Brave browser as per Nicolas Piquerez's suggestion and that resolved it for me too.